# Google Plus Media-Insert - Google Domains API - 403 Forbidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-plus

I am trying to upload an image to Google+ using Javascript/JQuery; I have an access token which I can use to authenticate POST requests successfully but I get the following response when I attempt to use G+ Media Insert (https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/media/insert):

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

I haven't configured Domain-wide delegation because I expect the user to sign in to generate the access token (is this perhaps the issue?). I have enabled the Google+ Domains API in the Developer console and the relevant scopes are in place but I can't figure out why I receive a 403 error. The following AJAX request is being used:

```
var postForm = new FormData();
postForm.append("source",[code which generated a blob]);
postForm.append("displayName", "TestUpload");

$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/plusDomains/v1/people/me/media/cloud",
    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + acToken},
    type:"POST",
    uploadType: "multipart/related",
    processData:false,
    contentType:false,
    cache:false,
    data: postForm,
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, I can provide more information if needed.

PS: I am actually using a userID instead of `me` in the URL for the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that the userID belongs to the user that you have authenticated (perhaps through this [OAuth flow](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/)). Unlike methods such as people.get, this method requires authentication, and cannot be called solely with an ID, unless that ID is the currently authenticated user. This is why we recommend using the special value `me` to avoid confusion.

Second, you need to be certain that the user that is authenticated is a Google Apps user. For example, if the user is a GMail user, the request will get a 403, since the Google+ Domains API is not allowed for non-Domains accounts.

Comment: Now that sounds like the caveat I'm missing, the user ID is a GMail account but I need this to work for any Google+ account... Which means there's nothing wrong with the code, just my ability to read documentation :) Could you recommend a method I should be using? My limitation is that I need a multipart form upload entirely in Javascript/JQuery as the image only exists on the client browsers memory.

Comment: I'm trying to create a new post with an image attached, from what I can tell this means inserting a "createActivity" moment but I can't see how to attach media. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The public Google+ API works for all Google+ users, but is currently read-only. So, there is not a solution to programmatically create a post with an attached image for any user at this time. You might look at writing App Activities, but these are not posts and currently do not surface in the Stream. You may also want to consider writing an Interactive Post, which is a sharing option that allows the developer to prefill the text of the post, but does not allow an image attachment.

Comment: Thanks for information Joanna, it doesn't look like this is going to be feasible so we have had to drop support for G+ until write access is available on the API. Having read around the subject I don't understand why Google are trying to compete in social media by denying access to one of the corner stones of social networking.